# Trouble trying to install OpenCv 3 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, opencv3.0

I am stuck trying to install and to compile OpenCV. When I try to install something with pip, for example

```
$ sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

I always get the following error :

> The directory '/home/..../.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> Collecting virtualenv
>   Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
>   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for virtualenv

And I have tried some ideas about this problem, for example first I tried with the following:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip setuptools
```

But nothing changed, also I update the pip install and now I have the version pip 18.1

I don't know if this problem it's because I installed Anaconda.

I hope someone could give me an advice and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, searching I found that this line: curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3,  solved the problem with pip.

Thanks